# how to troubleshoot the Gnome Classic Session?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, login, gnome-classic, gnome-session

I have installed **Ubuntu Gnome 14.04** and the *Gnome 3 stable + next + staging PPAs*. So I have Gnome 3.12 installed and it works OK apart from one issue:

In GDM I have the Gnome and Gnome Classic sessions. If I choose to start the default Gnome session it loads Gnome Shell and works ok, but if I choose Gnome Classic all I get is the GDM wallpaper and the mouse, no Gnome Shell with the 2 panels and default shell extensions for this session.

Afterwards I need to switch to tt1 and reboot or kill GDM.

If I run `startx gnome-classic-session` from `tty1` it loads OK but logging in from *GDM fails*. It worked sometime ago, just not now. I tried deleting all **Gnome config** files in my home directory but didn't work.

This is not for the Gnome Flashback session, it's for the new Classic session using Gnome Shell.

Any help? If anybody needs me to provide more info just ask away :)

Comment: The same issue here.