# Gnome Classic Session boots into a gray screen

Tags: 14.04, gnome-classic, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 with gnome shell version 3.12.In log-in screen there is three options : "System Default","Gnome Classic" & "Gnome". When I select "Gnome" there is no problem & I can use it flawlessly but if I select "Gnome Classic" it boots into a gray screen with a mouse pointer and nothing happened.So how can I open the "Gnome Classic".

PS: Here [how to troubleshoot the Gnome Classic Session?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/504864/how-to-troubleshoot-the-gnome-classic-session) is the same problem as of me.But there is no answer.

Comment: Did you try to rename temporarilly your ~/.gnome directory and restart your session?

Comment: No I have not.But how can I do that please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following solution worked:

1. Install the kernel

linux-image-3.15.0-031500rc2-generic_3.15.0-031500rc2.201404201435_amd64.deb

and the headers

linux-headers-3.15.0-031500rc2_3.15.0-031500rc2.201404201435_all.deb
linux-headers-3.15.0-031500rc2-generic_3.15.0-031500rc2.201404201435_amd64.deb

then reboot.

2. Install nvidia-331, bumblebee and primus

sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus

3. Edit the bumblebee.conf file

sudo gedit /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

line 22: Driver=nvidia
line 55: KernelDriver=nvidia-331
line 58: LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331
line 61: XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules

save and reboot

From [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1288572)

Answer (score 0):

Try out

1. ctr+alt+f1 and log in
2. `sudo service lightdm stop`
3. `mv ~/.gnome ~/.gnome_backup` or `mv ~/.config ~/.config_backup`
4. `sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: I am using gdm instead of lightdm.Though I have tried the above commands.But nothing happens.

Comment: did you try the same as above with ~/.config as http://askubuntu.com/questions/628468/kubuntu-15-04-alt-key-problem-after-upgrade it solved a problem for me...

Comment: No.But today I have installed ubuntu 15.04 with gnome shell version 3.14.So there is no issue now.